# Issue with paging when deleting object when using DeletObject (Entity Framework)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm having an issue with paging when I delete an object using the DeleteObject method (Entity Framework). The deletion works fine, as it is supposed to, but the page number is updated to the next page. I mean, if I'm deleting a record that is on page 3 of my search results, after the deletion is completed, the page number is updated to "page 4", even though the search results still correspond to page 3!

I have checked everything I could think of, but I can't figure out what is wrong. Has anyone had this problem before? (I'm pretty new to MVC, Razor, etc).

Thank you!

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code that does the paging and how it is called after the delete.

Comment: Please provide more details, code samples, ... so we can better answer your question. Right now it is downright impossible to guess what is going on in your application. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply, Gert Arnold and Moeri; I posted in a hurry going to a meeting and didn't add enough details.

As I went to grab the code to post here, I found the solution:

```
function DeleteRecord(SubscriptionID){
  var URL = "@Url.Content("~")PubSub/DeleteSubscriber/" + SubscriptionID;

  if(confirm("Are sure you want to delete this record?")){
  $.get(URL, function (data) {          
    if(data=="True")
    {            
        $("#SubscriptionContainer"+SubscriptionID).show();
        $("#Subscription"+SubscriptionID).html("<b><i>Delete Successful! Refreshing list please wait........</i></b>");
         window.setTimeout(function () {
              GetPage($("#PageNumber").val() - 1); //Adding the "- 1" solved the issue
           }, 2000);
    }                  
    });             
    }
}
```

To fix the code all I did was replacing GetPage($("#PageNumber").val(), with GetPage($("#PageNumber").val() - 1);